# MATLAB .m file to .mex file using Matlab Compiler

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I know it could souds as a very famous topic, but I didn't find anything that helps me with this.

This is the scenario:

1. I have a myFun.m function, no matter what's inside, it is a generic function which could potentially depends on other toolboxes. It has inputs and outputs;
2. I want to generate the analogous myFun.mex function;

I have Matlab Compiler and I can compile myFun.m as

```
mcc -v -W lib:libmyFun -T link:lib myFun
```

In this way I get some new files:

libmyfun.c

libmyfun.dll

libmyfun.exp

libmyfun.exports

libmyfun.h

libmyfun.lib

Reading around and following [Loren's example](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/) I guess I have to create a myfun.cpp which inside includes the very famous [gateway function](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html):

```
/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
/* variable declarations here */

/* code here */
}
```

I've tried to do that and called the mex generation routine:

```
mex('-v', 'myfun.cpp')
```

but I get several errors, and I must say my myfun.cpp is copy/paste function where I have a lot of doubts on... especially on inputs/outputs management.

My question is... apart from the myfun.cpp function which could be full of errors as I'm not a C/C++ developer... is the process correct?
If the answer is YES, does anybody knows which is the generic way to write the myfun.cpp?

Cheers,

Sebastian

Comment: Hello Daniel, many thanks for your answer. I always thought the mex command is for generating .mex starting from a C/C++ project... not from a .m file. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm almost certain that its `Matlab-coder` not compiler you are after... coder comes with a gui which can handle the process & gives decent error reports on compilation failure, if its available just type `coder` in the command window to run the gui (you can set output to mex in the build tab)

Comment: Hello RTL, thanks for your answer. Yuo are right, if you have a function you can generate a .mex file using the matlab coder, in a very easy way. The problem comes when you want to 'code' a function which includes other functions that are not allowed to be 'coded', for example functions from toolboxes like Neural Network. In this case the only thing you can do is to 'compile' the function... but again my problem is: after compiling a function... how can I generate a .mex function?

Comment: ah sorry, misunderstood/misread, that is beyond me at the moment then...

Comment: @sebas86: The Neural Network Toolbox provides a tool `genFunction` which can generate a MATLAB Coder-compliant MATLAB function to simulate a trained NN if that is what you need.  It is documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/genfunction.html) and has examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB Compiler does not do what you want.

MATLAB Compiler takes your `.m` code and encrypts and archives it into a `.ctf` (Component Technology File) file. It then produces a thin wrapper (either a `.exe` file, or a `.dll` library file along with files to enable calling the library from C). You deliver the `.ctf` file and the wrapper to your end user along with the freely redistributable MCR (MATLAB Compiler Runtime). It's possible to package either the first two or all three into a single unit for easier distribution.

The end user runs the executable or library, which dearchives and decrypts the `.m` code and runs it against the MCR rather than MATLAB. You can think of the MCR as basically a copy of MATLAB, but without the front-end desktop environment.

MATLAB Compiler is intended for the use case that you want to easily share a MATLAB application or algorithm with someone who does not have MATLAB. Because the code is encrypted, you can also use it to protect your intellectual property. But the code remains as `.m` code, and executes exactly as it would within MATLAB, including the same speed.

MEX is something different entirely. If you have an algorithm implemented in C code, you can add the 'gateway' routine you mention to it, and compile it with the command `mex` into a library that is then callable from MATLAB as if it were a regular MATLAB command or function. MEX functionality is part of regular MATLAB, and doesn't require any add-on products.

There is also another product, [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/), that is distinct from MATLAB Compiler.

MATLAB Coder takes `.m` code that is in a subset of the MATLAB language, and converts it to C code. The subset is very extensive, but there are a few significant restrictions on the parts of the MATLAB language that are supported. I'm afraid those restrictions include many toolbox functions, including some functionality from Neural Networks Toolbox.

You can then do lots of things with that C code, including using MEX to compile it back into a form usable as a MATLAB command. This can often, though not always, provide a significant speedup over the original `.m` code. You can also do other things such as integrate the C code into a wider C project. or deliver it to an embedded device.

The main answer to your question is:

1. MATLAB Compiler doesn't do what you need.
2. To produce a MEX file file from your `.m` code, either recode it manually into C and then mex it, or use MATLAB Coder to automatically produce C code and then mex it.

Comment: Hello Roberts, many thanks for your answer.Now the situation is much more clear to me about coder and compiler. Unfortunatelly, maybe because I've not been very good on explaining my requirements, I can't see any answer to my problem. Because of this, I try to explain what I actually need without mentioning any possible solution I've been investigating:(a)I have a function myFun.m which depends on some NNtoolb functions and (b)I want to share myFun.m with people who have matlab but the NNtb and who do not need to have acces to the function code. Is there any way to do that? Many thanks.

Comment: @sebas86 If your code is based on NN Toolbox, forget MATLAB Coder. Basically none of NN Toolbox is supported for generating C code. If your code applies pre-trained neural networks, MATLAB Compiler should be able to produce an executable from it. Your end-users will need neither NN Toolbox, nor even MATLAB itself, to use it. But if your code actually *trains* neural networks, that functionality is excluded from compilation with MATLAB Compiler as well. See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) for details. The only other method is...

Comment: @sebas86 ... to get your users a copy of Neural Network Toolbox, or to rewrite your code entirely so that it does not rely on the toolbox.

Comment: @Roberts Ok, I see your point. First, the myFun.m does not neet to train any NN,it just load a pre-trained NN saved somewhere on my machine.Second, I've tried to compile myFun.m and generate a .exe and it does work, if I call myFun.exe or myFun.m with the same input, I get the same output. But, using the .exe from Matlab is not very user-friendly, this is why I thought about a .mex function which calls a C/C++ library generate with Matlab Compiler but again the problem is: how can I create a .mex function starting from a C/C++ library generated with Matlab Compiler? Is this the correct way?

Comment: @sebas86 Why are you running the .exe from MATLAB? Just run the .exe. In addition, you don't need to create a mex function to call a C/C++ library - just use `loadlibrary`. You can only create a mex function from C source code, not from a library. But that's not relevant - either i) make a standalone executable with MATLAB Compiler and run it without MATLAB, or ii) get your users a copy of NN toolbox.

Comment: @Robert, another interesting point: "You can only create a mex function from C source code, not from a library".Thanks for that, I spent lot of time trying to generate a mex from the compiled version of myFun.m. So at this point the question is: how to 'use' the output of Matlab Compiler (which is toolbox indipendent!) in Matlab? having said that I want to answer your question: I need to distribute my function as something usable from matlab, so not as a .exe (not double click on the icon I mean but calling in some way from Matlab) and I need to pass inputs and to get outputs.

Comment: @sebas86 If you really want to, you can call your executable from MATLAB using the `system` command. You can pass in input arguments as text strings and receive output arguments as text strings, or you can pass inputs in a file and receive them in a file. Either way, you would need to add a bit of extra code at the beginning and end of your function, before compiling it, that would convert inputs and outputs to the required form. But the best solution would be to just buy your end-users a copy of NN Toolbox.

Comment: @Roberts Thanks Roberts. I would aboid buying NN toolbox to my end-users, they just need to see the output of the NN (i.e. my function use the 'sim' function to 'interrogate' the NN and the mapminmax function). So I will try to use the .exe, maybe creating a wrapping function like myfun_wrapping.m which inside calls the .exe using system command and preparing the input plus converting the output from string to what I need. Does it make sense?

Comment: News: I've tried to call a .exe using 'system' in the following way: [status,cmdout]=system('C:\myFun.exe 6','-echo'). The input is 6 but it enters the function as a string so I had to modify the function myFun.m such that the input is converted from string to num (num2str). For getting the output, the only way I've found is the 'disp' function in matlab. myFun.m looks like:

function out = myFun(in)
input = str2num(in)
...
...
disp(num2str(output))

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to display text like code in Comments. Anyway, using 'disp' I'm able to catch the output, I'm a bit surprised because when I run the .exe using 'system' command, it is quite slow, even if the .exe does just a output=input*2 operation

Comment: The reason it's slow is that every time you call it, it has to start up the MCR, which is almost as slow as starting MATLAB itself. This is one of the reasons that what you're doing is - while possible - not a very good idea. Like I say, the best solution is to buy NN Toolbox for your users.

Comment: I see, it does make sense. 
Thanks for the time you all guys spent answering my questions.
Sebastian